# Create a dynamic number of AppCheckBoxes from Repeater QML/JS

Tags: javascript, qt, loops, qml, repeater

I am looking to create a dynamic number of `AppCheckBox`, based on a repeater looping through an array.

I have been able to create the correct number of boxes I need, but am unable to now make the `text` of each `AppCheckBox` the element of the array it is the index of per section, my current code is:

```
property var departments: ({"Reception", "Stylist", "Technical", "Assistant"})
property var repeater: []

Repeater {
    model: {
        for(var i in departments) {
            repeater.push(departments[i])
            }
            console.log("REPEATER LENGTH " + repeater + repeater.length)
            repeater.length;
        }
    AppCheckBox {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        text: {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < repeater.length; i++) {
                text = repeater[i] ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

From the above code example, I am creating either 4 `AppCheckBox` with the text as the full array 4 times, or instead 4 check boxes of the final array element (in this case Assistant).

How could I make the text the 4 different array elements?

Thanks!

Comment: what are `Reception`, `Stylist`, `Technical`, `Assistant`?

Comment: Apologies @eyllanesc they are simply strings, which will change depending on the app user, I have altered my question to include `"` around them - this change is why I need the checkbox to be dynamic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set "departments" as a model if it is a list, and then access the information using the modelData property:

```
property var departments: ["Reception", "Stylist", "Technical", "Assistant"]

Repeater {
    model: departments
    AppCheckBox {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        text: model.modelData
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million! I seemed to be overthinking it there :)